# On abelian subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite
field of order $p$. Let $G=GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ denote the general linear
group and $U_{n}$ denote the unitriangular group of $n\times n$ upper
triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal, over the finite field $%
\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Let $H$ be an abelian subgroup of order $p^{m}$ in $U_{n}$. Does the subgroup $H$ must be elementary abelian of rank $m$ ( $H\simeq (\mathbb{F}_{p})^{m})$.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: Every finite group of order $n$ arises as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(p)$ acting as permutation matrices. So in particular this applies to groups that are abelian but not elementary abelian. So the answer to your qustion must be no. (But it is yes when $n \le p$.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no for $n=4$, $p=3$ and $m=2$. The group $UT(4,3)$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $9$.

Comment: More generally ${\rm UT}(p+1,p)$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\mathcal H$ is an abelian $p$ subgroup of upper unitriangular matrices in $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb F_p)$ and choose $\mathbf T:=(t_{ab})_{1\leq a,b\leq n}\in\mathcal H$. Choose any $k,1< k\leq n,$ satisfying $\mathbf T^p\cdot\vec{\mathbf v}_j=\vec{\mathbf v}_j$ for all $j<k$ where $$\vec{\mathbf v}_j:=(t_{1j},\dots,t_{jj},0,\dots,0)=t_{1j}\mathbf e_1+\cdots +t_{jj}\mathbf e_j$$ is column $j$ of $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf e_j$ denotes column $j$ of the identity matrix. Consequently, we should also have $\mathbf T^p\cdot\mathbf e_j=\mathbf e_j$ for all $j<k$ . 
Therefore, $$\mathbf T^p\cdot\vec{\mathbf v}_k=\mathbf T^p\cdot (t_{1k}\mathbf e_1+\cdots +t_{kk}\mathbf e_k)=\mathbf T^p\cdot\mathbf e_k+\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\mathbf T^r\cdot(\vec{\mathbf v}_k-\vec{\mathbf e}_k)=\mathbf T^p\cdot\mathbf e_k+(\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\mathbf T^r)\cdot(\vec{\mathbf v}_k-\vec{\mathbf e}_k)=\vec{\mathbf v}_k$$

By induction we must have $\mathbf T^p\cdot\vec{\mathbf v}_j=\vec{\mathbf v}_j$ for all $j$ and therefore $\mathbf T^p=\mathbf I$ is the identity matrix. Consequently, $\mathbf X^p=\mathbf I$ for all $\mathbf X\in\mathcal H$. Therefore, from the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups we must have $\mathcal H\approx\Bbb F_p^{+m}=\Bbb F_p^+\times\cdots\times\Bbb F_p^+$.